# Ajax getting called more than once

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a link in my html and upon clicking that ajax will be called with certain parameters. Ajax in turn calls the servlet which inturn calls an unix script.

The problem happening is the unix script is getting called multiple times.
I have also added alert boxes to understand how it is getting called multiple times, but the alerts are coming only twice as expected (there are 2 alerts).

I have tried multiple options like stopEventPropagation, using a flag to restrict the call of ajax if one is already running. But nothing seems to work. Please help.

Below is my ajax calling function and html link.

```js
var activityRunning = false;

function collectForDeployment(event, smopId, componentId, activityId){ 
 ///alert 1
 alert('Outside If: '+activityRunning);

 if($('#noscript_'+componentId+activityId).length>0){
  alert('No script found to deploy');
 }else{  
  if(!activityRunning){
          ///alert 2
   alert('Inside If: '+activityRunning);
   checkForUserNamePass(componentId, "<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("CONTEXT_ROOT").toString()%>/ajaxservlet?action=actDeployment&smopId="+smopId+"&componentId="+componentId+"&activityId="+activityId+"&environment="+$('#environment').val(),function(urlString){ 
    //alert(urlString); 
       $.ajax({
           url: urlString,        
           method: 'post', 
           tryCount : 0,
           retryLimit : 0,
           beforeSend: function(){       
            $('#backgroundDiv').hide();
              document.getElementById("divBackground").style.display="block";
              event = event || window.event;
           stopEventPropagation(event);
           },
           success: function(data) {  
            var newLocation = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/EditSmopPopup.jsp?randomKey="+Math.random()+"&componentId="+$('#selectedComponent').val().replace('#','')+"&smopId=<%=request.getParameter("smopId")%>&environment="+$('#environment').val()+"&articleId="+$('#selectedComponent').val()+"&divId="+$('#selectedActivity').val();         
            window.location.href=newLocation;
            $('#backgroundDiv').hide();
            var popUpObj=window.open("",
              "View Deployment Log for SMOP Id : " + smopId + " : ComponentId : " + componentId + " : Activity Id : " + activityId,
              "toolbar=no," +
              "scrollbars=no," +
              "location=no," +
              "statusbar=no," +
              "menubar=no," +
              "resizable=0," +
              "width=650," +
              "height=450," +
              "left = 350," +
              "top=170"
              );
            popUpObj.document.title="View Deployment Log for SMOP Id : " + smopId + " : ComponentId : " + componentId + " : Activity Id : " + activityId;
            popUpObj.document.body.innerHTML=data;         
         popUpObj.focus();
         document.getElementById("divBackground").style.display="none";
         event = event || window.event;
         stopEventPropagation(event);
           }
       });
   });
  }else{
   return;
  } 
  activityRunning = true;
  event = event || window.event;
  stopEventPropagation(event);
 }
}



function checkForUserNamePass(componentId, urlString, callback){ 
 var finalString;
 if($('#'+componentId+"_passreq").val()=='Y'){
  $("#divAdmin").show();
  $("#fadeAdmin").show();  
  $("#btnLogin").click(function(event){
   if($('#txtAdminUser').val() == '' || $('#txtAdminPass').val() == ''){
    alert('Please enter the Admin user name or password to proceed');
    event = event || window.event;
    stopEventPropagation(event);
   }else{
    finalString = urlString+"&adminuser="+$('#txtAdminUser').val()+"&adminpass="+$('#txtAdminPass').val();
    $("#divAdmin").hide();
    $("#fadeAdmin").hide();  
    event = event || window.event;
    stopEventPropagation(event);
    callback(finalString);
   }
    
  });
 }else{
  finalString = urlString;
  callback(finalString);
 } 
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
     id="a_<%=dto1.getComponentId()+dto2.getActivityId()%>"
     onclick="collectForDeployment(event, '<%=request.getParameter("smopId")%>', '<%=dto2.getComponentId()%>', '<%=dto2.getActivityId()%>')"><img
      border="0" alt="Deploy Individual Activity"
      title="Deploy Individual Activity"
      src="<%=request.getSession()
           .getAttribute("CONTEXT_ROOT")
           .toString()%>/images/deploy.png"
      width="20px"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is explained here...
http://geek.starbean.net/?p=393